# error: invalid declarator before with typedef

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef

```
#ifndef CLASS_VEHICLE_
#define CLASS_VEHICLE_

#include "ns3/ptr.h"
#include "ns3/object.h"
#include "ns3/vector.h"
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/config-store-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"
#include "Cluster.h"


namespace ns3
{
class Cluster;

/// define type DeviceTraceCallback
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, std::string, Ptr<const Packet> > DeviceTraceCallback;  // Line where the error is
/// define type VehicleReceiveCallback.
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, Ptr<const Packet>, Address> VehicleReceiveCallback;
/// define type PhyRxOkTraceCallback.
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, std::string, Ptr<const Packet>, double, WifiMode, enum WifiPreamble> PhyRxOkTraceCallback; 
/// define type PhyRxErrorTraceCallback.
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, std::string, Ptr<const Packet>, double> PhyRxErrorTraceCallback; 
/// define type PhyTxTraceCallback.
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, std::string, Ptr<const Packet>, WifiMode, WifiPreamble, uint8_t> PhyTxTraceCallback; 
/// define type PhyStateTraceCallback.
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, std::string, Time, Time, enum WifiPhy::State> PhyStateTraceCallback;

class Vehicle : public ns3::Object
{
  ... code section

 };
};
#endif
```

I am working on ns3, and I've to implement a code which could let me do some simulations about vehicular networks. I have several classes, but only one is annoying. Indeed when I compile I have this particular error:

> "/src/vanet/model/Vehicle.h:45: error: invalid declarator before ‘DeviceTraceCallback’"

and it brings a tons other errors as

> "/src/vanet/model/Vehicle.h:212: error: ‘DeviceTraceCallback’ does not name a type"

or

> "../src/vanet/model/Vehicle.h:214: error: ‘DeviceTraceCallback’ has not been declared".

I really don't understand what I did wrong, so if someone could help me it would be very nice!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the FAQ and provide a minimal, compilable example (i.e. with all the `#includes`) that displays the problem.

Comment: Please try editing that code down to the _minimum_ that reproduces the problem - just delete everything after the bad declaration and remove everything you can before it without introducing new errors. It's much easier for everyone else to read the _relevant_ code when it isn't surrounded by code that's _irrelevant_ to the problem. As a bonus, you can sometimes figure the problem out yourself during the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown us which source line the error refers to, but I'll assume it's this one:

```
typedef Callback<void, Ptr<Vehicle>, std::string, Ptr<const Packet> > DeviceTraceCallback;
```

Have all the types and templates mentioned in that line been declared in one of the headers you've included? In particular:

- You haven't directly included `<string>`. It's a good idea to do that, even if one of the other headers might include it indirectly.
- You haven't declared the `Vehicle` type, defined later in this file. You'll need a declaration (`class Vehicle;` inside `namespace ns {}`) before you can use it in this declaration.

Comment: Thx for your fast answer, yes I have included <string> in another header. I don't understand the second point because in fact it is the Vehicle class, so I have to put class Vehicle before the typedef ?

Comment: And I forgot something, in fact the error is at the first typedef line but if I switch the order of the typedef, it will be still the first typedef line the error line.

Comment: @Demyke: Yes, you have to declare `Vehicle` before the `typedef`. Just add the line `class Vehicle;` before the typedef; you don't have to move the whole class definition.

Comment: Ok thx a lot, it works !! 2 days I'm looking for an answer !!