# invalid declarator before ‘MY_MAP’

Tags: dictionary, typedef

Trying to make a map with strings as the key and a custom class Link as the stored value, but keep getting the error in the title. Here's what I have:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Link>  MY_MAP;
```

And the Link class:

```
class Link{

typedef  std::map<std::string, Link>  map_type;

public:
Link(){ next = NULL; val = 0; };
~Link(){ delete next; };
std::string key;
int val;
map_type* next;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolve this problem ?

Can this be your solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885783/error-invalid-declarator-before-with-typedef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Link class definition should end with a semicolon after the last curly bracket.